# FireFox and AjaxControlToolKit Combobox

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I'm using the .NET framework 4.0 and the corresponding version of the Ajax control toolkit.

On my page I have a combobox defined like this:

```
<asp:ComboBox ID="cbUserName" AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend"
        CaseSensitive="false" runat="server" BackColor="#FFFFCC">
        </asp:ComboBox>
```

In IE9 the combobox allows me to either type in it or select from the list of users. In FireFox, however, it's not letting me type in the box. The dropdownlist also doesn't filter when I'm typing in FireFox either. I'm wondering if anyone else has seen this behavior, and if there's a work-around?

**EDIT**

For what it's worth, the demo on the ASP.NET Ajax Control Toolkit site actually works fine in FireFox.

Comment: if you already mentioned in your edit that the combox on ASP.NET Ajax Control Toolkit works then what else are you looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The similar issue has been reported [here](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/27215), make sure you used the same version of firefox and toolkit. If not try to upgrade them and again try.

Comment: I've upgraded to FireFox 15.0 and still can't type in the textbox.

Comment: Could you download the .Net Framework 4.0 specific toolkit site and check out whether it works in Firefox? if it is then try to reference that dll in your project and check again. Though similar issue has been reported, if it works in the sample site it should work for you as well.

Answer (score 12):

I was also getting the problem of not being able to enter text into a `Combobox` in FireFox, but I could in IE and Chrome. After a day of looking into the problem I found that setting the `MaxLength` property to something greater than 0 allowed FireFox to accept entry in the text field for the combobox.

I hope this helps someone having the same problem.

Comment: @Elvieejo Words such as "firefox", "IE", and "Chrome" are not code, and should not be highlighted as code. Really, only `MaxLength` here is code, and it's not especially helpful to have highlighted that in this case.

Comment: You just saved me a ton of time, Bob.

Comment: Well dang. That is a pretty nonsensical default. Thanks for noticing that and posting about it!

Comment: Thank you. I had same problem in Chrome, but I found workaround with             ComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0. And after same issue was in FireFox. So complete solution was ComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;     ComboBox.MaxLength = ComboBox.Items.Count;

Comment: Bob's answer should be marked as right answer. I was unaware this is only FF issue, because I start pages in FF by default. I almost gave up on this and then I found this thread. Thanks a lot guys :)

Answer (score 2):

```
ddlBox.SelectedIndex = 0
```

Until the latest iteration of Ajax control toolkit, I didn't need to set that.  But then I updated, and I couldn't type into the empty text box, which used to be displayed with the first item.  So I added that code and it works fine again.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ajaxToolkit:ComboBox ID="ComboBox1" runat="server" DropDownStyle="DropDownList" AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend" CssClass="" AppendDataBoundItems="false">  
       <asp:ListItem>Fox</asp:ListItem> 
</ajaxToolkit:ComboBox>
```

This worked for me in firefox.

Im not sure if you mistaking the ability to type but a combobox will only allow you to type out the ListItems. so in this case it will only allow you to type out `Fox`..

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it still didn't work. I'm not able to type *anything* in the textbox associated with the ComboBox control. I can pick the drop-down and select an item in FireFox, but I can't type inside the textbox (which is weird, because on the toolkit demo site, FireFox works fine).

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem. I couldn't find an elegant solution online so I built my own AjaxControlToolkit.dll from two different sets of the toolkit source code.

I used everything from the latest release except for I replaced ComboBox.cs and ComboBox.pre.js with their versions from AjaxControlToolkit_8502f32ba9ce. (~July 2011)

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
ajaxToolkit:ComboBox ID="ComboBox1" runat="server" DropDownStyle="DropDownList"
AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend" CssClass="" AppendDataBoundItems="false"
MaxLength="100"
```