# ComboBox of AjaxControlToolkit v4 is not allowed to type in latest Chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

We are using `v4` of `AjaxControlToolkit` for our project, now we have an issue that the `ComboBox` is not allowed to type in latest Chrome (51.xxx). I tried and it did work in an early version (40.xxx I tested with).

This is the way how the `ComboBox` is created.

```
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
$create(Sys.Extended.UI.ComboBox, {"autoCompleteMode":3,
                                    "autoPostBack":false,
                                    "buttonControl":$get("comboBox2_comboBox2_Button"),
                                    "comboTableControl":$get("comboBox2_comboBox2_Table"),
                                    "dropDownStyle":1,
                                    "hiddenFieldControl":$get("comboBox2_comboBox2_HiddenField"),
                                    "optionListControl":$get("comboBox2_comboBox2_OptionList"),
                                    "selectedIndex":4,
                                    "textBoxControl":$get("comboBox2_comboBox2_TextBox")}, 
null, null, $get("comboBox2"));
});
```

Is this an known issue?

I'm wondering if there are any workaround for this without upgrading to the latest version?

Thanks in advance!

**Update:**

I found that it's not working with the latest Firefox either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11523525/firefox-and-ajaxcontroltoolkit-combobox) by setting `MaxLength` property to something greater than 0.